# Using JQuery detach and restore to filter a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Ms9NY/

I'm using jquery and trying to use detach/prepend/append to dynamically remove and reinsert option items on a select.

Because hiding options does not work cross browser, the only way to really get it to function as needed is removing the options completely.

I can remove the items with detach but I'm lost on how to restore them later. I know I would need to add them to an array somehow but I can't figure out how to do that. **How can I use an array to detach and restore only specifically matched items from the deleted list?**

This is what I have been testing with:

```
$("#filter-specs-text").keyup(function(){
        var searchString = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $("#specs-excluded-select>option").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

                //found a match - show this entry
                if ( text.indexOf(searchString) > -1 ) {
                    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $(this).prependTo("#specs-excluded-select");                    
                }

                //no match - hide this entry
                else {                                          
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $(this).detach();
                }
        });
```

Visual reference. The filter box is the text box noted by the arrow.

[image]

Comment: you should provide a jsFiddle, easier to help

Comment: Yes, good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms9NY/

Comment: I cleaned up some of the extra stuff and streamlined it so it can help many other people looking to do the same: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms9NY/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle it like this instead:

### --DEMO--

```
var $opts = $("#specs-excluded-select>option"); // keeping there all options

$("#filter-specs-text").keyup(function () {
    var searchString = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#specs-excluded-select").empty().append($opts); // append() to keep any data/events bound to options
    $("#specs-excluded-select>option").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        //found a match - show this entry
        if (text.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        }

        //no match - hide this entry
        else {
           $(this).prop("disabled", true).detach();
        }
    });

});
```